# Is it necessary to have lessons when creating scorm?

Tags: php, scorm

I have authoring tool which creates Assement in HTML and/or Flash format. 
I do not have any tool for creating lessons. Now i want to make the assessments created to SCORM compliant
Can it be compliant without any lessons ?
Any SCORM libraries for PHP where i can create and test it for compliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to have a lesson to be SCORM conformant. The "content" that is delivered by SCORM is a black box, it can contain anything. It is perfectly valid to make a SCORM package that is just an assessment.

As far as using PHP is concerned, you might need to a bit careful. Are you looking to create the lesson/assessment in PHP? Or, are you looking to create a simple tracking LMS in PHP?

If you are trying to create the content in PHP, you will probably want to re-evaluate. While not technically illegal, you can almost never deploy content that contains server-side code to an LMS. If you are trying to host the content yourself, you will run into difficulties with the cross domain scripting problem that aren't trivial to overcome.

If you need a place to test out your content, try [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud/).

Comment: - I have system that generates assessment in HTML/Flash by using PHP. But they are not scorm compliant . so i want to make them scorm compliant either 1.2 or 2004 
Any libraies in PHP that willl helpt build my assessments SCORM compliant